# Problem running steps inside custom docker container using GitHub Action

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I'm using GH actions for testing a GO application, I created on docker-hub a custom image (guerra1994/go-mqtt-docker) with docker(DiD)/go/mosquitto and in action file I just used with label `container:`. (my expectation is it runs all steps inside the container)

In one test of the application, there is a test that checks `docker ps -a` command, I expect that return empty result but it returns one container is present, that container is mine like container runs by the runner of actions see "host" container or maybe it creates as "brother" container and not as "child".

I don't really understand what is happening... Some can help me?

Another workaround is to create an executable docker image that runs all command to execute tests directly in `ENTRYPOINT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probel is `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` that allows your container to see other in your host machine